# how i change default url ('/') to ('home/landing/page')

Tags: laravel, authentication

How can i change default **routes** 
`('/')` to `('home/landing/page')` ?
i change in Authenticate but it's doesn't work.

[image: in Authenticate]
and this eror
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you need to add a route to your `routes.php` file or your `web.php` file depending on what version of Laravel you are using. It should look something like this:

```
Route::get('home/landing/page', 'SomeController@function`);
```

Obviously replacing `SomeController@function` for your controller and the appropriate function. This is why you're currently getting an error as no route is setup.

Next you might want to update your `AuthController.php` to include:

```
private $redirectTo = 'home/landing/page';
```

This ensures that after users login they are redirected to the right page.

Lastly, you may want to redirect any requests to `/` to redirect to the new page `home/landing/page`. You can do this in your routes, a controller or with middleware, the choice is yours. Here is a demo doing it in the routes file:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect('home/landing/page');
});
```

With all the above, and your auth middleware redirecting users to `home/landing/page`, you should have covered all bases for when users will hit your `/` route.

Comment: @dwikyaliansyah it's in my answer already, use the `private $redirectTo = 'home/landing/page';` in your `AuthController.php`